# Sort ListView in ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I've created a `ListActivity` (yeah, the one without an XML layout) which displays the values got from an `ArrayList<String>`, via an `adapter`.

The fact is that the last String added to the `ArrayList`, is the latest to appear on the `ListView` aswell, instead I want to sort the `ListView` so that the **last** item added will be the **first** one on **top** in the `ListView`, how to do it?

Look, this is a snippet of my application, about the `onCreate()` method of the `ListActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> history = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("HistoryList");

    ListView historyList = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history);
    historyList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing complicated. You just needed to reverse the list history.

```
Collections.reverse(history);
```

You should read a little about the theory of Java and learn how to look for. Otherwise, nothing good is not over. The code would look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> history = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("HistoryList");
    Collections.reverse(history);
    ListView historyList = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history);
    historyList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the fact is I read a Java book, now I'm reading the -android one, but I'm not a beast on Java, just know how to moove on it.. a bit

Comment: That's why I'm creating an App

Answer (score 1):

> how to do it?

Re-order `history` to be in the order that you want, such as [via `Collections.reverse()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a Comparator to sort the string.

Comment: I think I'll need to ask you how to do it, new to this